# L'Hospital's rule's hypothesis that the right hand limit should exist

Tags: limits

Why does the l'Hospital's rule assume that the right hand limit should exist? How does it work for x ln(-x) as x tends to 0 from the the left hand side?

Comment: when talking about the right hand limit you should write it down so people can see what's on the right hand of your formula.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule will work just fine for your example, and give limit $0$. Because negative numbers make me nervous, I would let $t=-x$ and study $-\frac{\ln t}{1/t}$ as $t$ approaches $0$ from the right. But that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The derivatives may behave *worse* than the functions themselves. Consider $f(x)=x^2\sin\frac1x$ (for $x\ne 0$) and $g(x)=x$, so $f'(x)=2x\sin \frac1x-\cos \frac1x$ and $g'(x)=1$. Now we have
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2\sin\frac1x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\frac1x=0$$
whereas $ \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=2x\sin \frac 1x-\cos\frac1x$ diverges as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\ln(-x)$, we can re-write this as $$\frac{\ln(-x)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Now L'Hospitals rule actually states that if we take the derivative of the top and bottom and get a finite number (or $\pm\infty$), then the limit is the same as the original limit.

However, if we take the derivatives, we get

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$

and as $x$ goes to zero, this limit is clearly undefined. Thus L'Hopital's rule does not apply here.

Reference [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html).

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$    Doesn't this tend to zero as x tends to zero from the left hand side? Isn't l'Hospital's rule applicable for the left hand limit